# Set cell to NULL in a sqlsrv_query's prepared statement

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, sqlsrv

In my table `MyTable` I have a field `MyField` whose type is `numeric(8,0)` and I am creating a Php script, connecting to this Sql Server Database.

This is the code I am using

```
  $sql = "INSERT INTO MyTable VALUES(?);";
  $stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql, array($myVal));
```

And it works fine most of the time. The problem arises when `myVal` is an empty string (inserted from an Html form). In that case I receive the following error:

> [message] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL
> Server]Error converting data type varchar to numeric.

If this is the case, I'd like the value in the database to be "NULL". In fact, if I execute the following statement: `INSERT INTO MyTable VALUES(NULL);` directly into the database it works fine and as intended, but I am not able to accomplish the same Php-side.

I tried to overcome it in this way:

```
if (myVal == ""){ myVal = "NULL"; }
if (myVal == ""){ myVal = "null"; }
if (myVal == ""){ myVal = null; }
if (myVal == ""){ myVal = NULL; }
```

But they do not work.

Comment: Setting your parameter to `null` should work just fine. Try doing a `vardump` of `$myVal` before running the query to confirm the type and value of that variable.

Comment: I am not PHP guy, but shouldn't your array($myVal) return as many values as columns in MyTable? setting myVal to null will just return a single column from the array. I believe you should encapsulate complete logic inside the conditional block, and do not execute if myVal is null or empty.

Comment: If $myVal is NULL from HTML then still you want to insert value into DB?

Comment: You need to check the input values before the statement execution. Another option is to use a different T-SQL statement: `$sql = "INSERT INTO MyTable (MyField) VALUES(TRY_CONVERT(numeric(8, 0), ?));";` Also note, that if you set `$myVal` to `null` (`$myVal = null;`), the statement executes correctly.